# В EIP указан адрес на ntdll. Что делать?

Tags: overflow, buffer

Следую этому гайду. https://samsclass.info/127/proj/p10-easymp3-with-aslr.htm

По гайду там в Immunity Debugger Access violation when executing [41414141]. Но у меня в EIP указан адрес на ntdll. Почему так? Что делать?

thx

Answer (score 0):

Нашел ответ. Согласно автору, если мы напишем 1032 «А», мы сможем увидеть «АААА» в регистре EIP.

Это предполагает, что программа была скомпилирована без (теперь стандартных) проверок безопасности во время выполнения.

https://reverseengineering.stackexchange.com/questions/12307/why-cant-i-get-the-eip-to-reflect-my-input